# Is there a Rest API to verify in app purchases?

Tags: android, google-play

Newbie question, I am making an android app with in-app purchases and there is a nice tutorial on how to do this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html). However I can't find how I would verify that purchase on my server. i.e. Client buys 10 gummy bears etc and tells the server add these to my profile. How do I check whether the client is telling the truth before updating the profile? Is there a rest based api somewhere to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, sort off. You get a signed response from app store on your device as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html). The response is signed using your merchant key so you can verify using your keys on your server without making a rest call. The message to watch out for is the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED with a financial-order-state or CHARGED. Send that to your server and just verify the signature.

Alternatively, I think you can integrate with the google checkout [Notification API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html) but this may not play nice with the in app purchase because it relies on your notifications being handled by a service on the device.